# Как считать один символ и передать его функции? Консоль

Tags: c, char, символы

Прошу объяснить где ошибка:

Пишу в Visual Studio 2017 15.2

Вообщем есть задача: нужно нарисовать квадрат символов (символ вводим) с размером стороны которую тоже вводим.

Суть проблемы ввод самого символа. В книжке (из которой задача) предлагают вызывать через `getchar()`, но через нее тоже не работает. Например в моей последней попытке дошло до того, что один раз цикл выполняется нормально, символ вводится, размер стороны вводится, квадрат рисуется. Но как только начинается вторая (и последующие) итерация цикла, то момент когда нужно ввести символ просто игнорируется и вместо символа вводится `\n` (При отладке символьная переменная на моменте `scanf_s("%c", &symbol, 1)`; записывается как `\n` (хочу заметить, что в этот момент я ничего не нажимаю, тем более enter)) И в итоге рисуются квадраты из переходов на новую строку, выглядит это стремно.

Так вот есть несколько вопросов:

1) Почему так происходит?

2) Почему не работает `getchar()` ?

3) Почему не ловит символ `scanf`?

4) Как было бы правильно записать этот момент кода по всем правилам хорошего стиля программирования? (Без слишком сложных элементов)

5) Еще я пробовал убирать амперсaнд и ставить `scanf_s("%s", symbol)`; и все равно не ловит, почему?

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // Это я пробовал вызов символа через scanf без _s
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <time.h>

    void square(int, char); // Прототип фунции

    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");

        int side = 1;
        char symbol;


        while (side != 0)
    {

        printf("Введите длину стороны квадрата: ");
        scanf("%i", &side);

        printf("Введите символ: ");
        scanf("%c", &symbol);
        while (getchar() != '\n')
        {
            continue; // Вызов функции рисования квадратика
        }
        square(side, symbol);

    }



        system("pause");

        return 0;
    }

    void square(int x, char y)
    {
        int i = 1, n = 1;
        for (n = 1; n <= x; n++) // Формируем ряд
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) // Записываем ряд
            {
                printf_s("%c", y);
            }
            printf_s("\n"); // Переходим на новую строку
        }
    }
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ф-ция `getchar()` возвращает код введенного символа - когда вы нажимаете на ентер - это тоже символ! Символ новой строки. Поэтому нужно либо дополнить код:

```
while (getchar()!='/n') continue;
```

либо использовать `scanf`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70309/discussion-on-answer-by-andrej-levkovitch-------).